# HTML5 Media Queries on iOS6

Tags: html, cordova, ios6, media

I have developed an iOS app in PhoneGap. It was working perfect but when i upgraded my iOS SDK to version 6.0, the media queries I was working with are now not effective anymore. Does iOS 6 has any issues regarding media queries?

Comment: Can you post a specific example of the media query you are using that now fails? ...is one query failing, or a variety of different ones?

Comment: I am using the iPad emulator and here i am dealing with the orientation related queries `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)
            { // css }`